# Redirect в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

поставил RBAC и если недостаточно прав выходил страница с номером ошибки. Как сделать так что бы если ошибка 403 то был редирект на страницу со входом? попытался прямо во вьюхе сделать что то вроде

```
if ($this->exception==403) Yii->app-response->redirect
```

есть предложения?

Answer (score 1):

Во первых если у Вас Yii2, то функция редиректа неверная.

Во вторых можно отловить исключение таким образом (**В представлении - View**):

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
if (Yii::$app->response->getStatusCode() == 403) {
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(['home/index']));
}
```

Также можете обработать ошибку в **контроллере** таким способом:

```
use yii\helpers\Url;
if (Yii::$app->response->getStatusCode() == 403) {
    return $this->redirect(Url::to(['home/index']));
}
```

Где **Home** - Контроллер, **Index** - Действие